# kafka http sink connector not sending data to URL hosted by Node

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Iam following this link https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-http/current/index.html#http-connector-header-forwarding

this is the project file , im using https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-http-demo

I have done configuring everything, but I could not able to send requested body to the URL which was hosted by Node/Python.

Could someone suggest any changes in configuration.

```
{
 "name": "test1",
 "config":
 {
    "topics": "kafka-data",
    "request.method": "POST",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector",
    "http.api.url": "http://localhost:3000/api/messages",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "reporter.result.topic.name": "success-responses",
    "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.error.topic.name":"error-responses",
    "reporter.error.topic.replication.factor":"1"
  }
}
```

URL was hosted using Node.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let tempContainer = [];
app.get('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ 'all watchers': tempContainer })
})

app.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    console.log('your req.body:', req.body);
    req.body.id = 'randumId_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    tempContainer.push(req.body)
    res.send({ 'watchers log updated': req.body })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

this is my node code
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to need to some server logs from the Connect worker to show that something should be happening. Did you actually get the demo working?

Comment: yeah demo is working but when i provide another url then its not working

Comment: Can you please show your Node code as part of a [mcve]? And again, any logs?

Comment: I have added my node code...

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find why body was empty?

Comment: Although I use different (not confluent) http connector, I do have the same problem. So far what I found was that "Content-Type" header is not being sent to my server (express), so body-parser middleware is not able to determine the type of content it receives. You can manually set the header value (depends on your messages format) before parsing, and you should get your message inside req.body. Of course, this does not solve the original problem of the header not being sent.